# How to type class extension so that constructor for the class accepts expected type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

This is the closest I've come to so far.  This is a dumbed down version of the extension I have, but it gets the point across.

Essentially I have a function that generates a new class which extends Immutable.Record.  I want to be able specify type down the line.

In the code snippet below `{ a: '5' }` gives me the following error:

Cannot call `Test` with object literal bound to `values` because object literal [1] is incompatible with `T` [2].)

```js
export function ExtendModel<T: Object>(obj: T) {
  return class extends Immutable.Record({ ...obj }) {
    constructor(values?: T) {
      return super(values);
    }
  };
}

type TestFlow = {
  a?: string,
};

class Test extends ExtendModel<TestFlow>({
  a: undefined,
}) {}

const testInstance = new Test({ a: '5' })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js"></script>
```